# Mac OSX .bash_profile export path with spaces

Tags: shell, terminal

I'm probably doing something obvious wrong here.
In $HOME/.bash_profile I've added (note the space in the path):

```
export PROJ="~/Documents/project livefeed"
```

After that I get:

```
➜  ~ cd $PROJ                  
cd: no such file or directory: ~/Documents/project livefeed
```

Any idea what's wrong? I've attempted adding a backslash before the space between the quotes, but this didn't help either.

The folder exists:

```
➜  ~ cd ~/Documents/project\ livefeed
➜  project livefeed
```

Also I applied:

```
➜  ~ source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

`~` doesn't get expanded inside `""`. To make it work, use

```
export PROJ=~/"Documents/project livefeed"
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it also didn't work.

Comment: Did you try it as: `cd "$PROJ"`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a charming feature (or woeful wart) of POSIX shells. You'll need to *always* quote the `$PROJ` variable (so `cd "$PROG"` everywhere and time you interpolate that variable) or instead use some other shell such as ZSH that does not do the POSIX word split thing.

```
% mkdir "a dir"
% dir="a dir"
% cd $dir
% pwd
/Users/jhqdoe/tmp/a dir
% cd ..
% bash
bash-3.2$ dir="a dir"
bash-3.2$ cd $dir
bash: cd: a: No such file or directory
bash-3.2$ exit
exit
%
```

Comment: Well it's a coincidence, I use zsh, but it doesn't work. Can you post the solution in terms of what I have? I've tried adding quotes `cd "$PROJ"`but this isn't working either.

Comment: I suspect the quoted ~ is the problem here.

Comment: @JeffSchaller When changing to the actual `/Users/username` directory it isn't actually working either. I guess that I miss the complete solution here, probably missing something obvious.

Comment: Since the error message in the question *includes* the space, this is clearly not the issue.